Problem with unzipping multi part zip files using Python
I need to unzip a multi part zip file using python function ensuring it is cross pltform compatible (Linux, Windows and MacOS).
The folder structure is the following:
project-root/
├── data.z01
├── ...
├── data.z22
└── data.zip

I triesd the following Python code:
def _combine_split_zip_files(split_files, combined_file):
    with open(combined_file, 'wb') as wfd:
        for f in tqdm(split_files, file=TqdmLogger(logger)):
            with open(f, 'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)

def _unzip_protected_zip(zip_file, extract_to, password):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall(path=extract_to, pwd=password.encode())

split_files = [root / f"data.z{i:02d}" for i in range(1, 23)] + [root / "data.zip"]
combined_file = root / "combined.zip"

_combine_split_zip_files(split_files, combined_file)
_unzip_protected_zip(combined_file, root / "data", ZIP_PW)

The __combine_split_zip_files() seams to work since it generate a combined.zip files that could be extracted by the Linux zip extractor. But unfortunately zipfile does not recognize the combined file and return the following error: zipfile.BadZipFile: zipfiles that span multiple disks are not supported.
Just for testing I've tried to combine the multiple zip part using the following bash command
zip -F data.zip --out combined.zip

Combining the multiplle part zip file using this method lead to a combined.zip file that is correctly recognize also by zipfile.
There is a way to merge the multiple part of the zip in a correcct way using just Python code?

You can read the files into memory as a io.BytesIO object, which can then be read directly into a ZipFile object for extraction.
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

def multipart_file(files: list[str]) -> BytesIO:
    fp = BytesIO()
    for f in files:
        fp.write(Path(f).read_bytes())
    fp.seek(0)
    return fp

def unzip_multipart(files: list[str], extract_to: str, password: str):
    mpf = multipart_file(files)
    with ZipFile(mpf) as zf:
        zf.extractall(path=extract_to, pwd=password.encode())

For the files you listed, typically the multipart zip files do not include the data.zip file.  So you would run this using:
unzip_multipart([root / f"data.z{i:02d}" for i in range(1, 23)])


I've tried your proposed solution but unfortunately I've got the same error by ZipFile. The process of fusing the part of the zip files by concatenating the byte seams to be incorrect. I think is required a smarter way of fusing them.
